Click: Take user options that aren't pre-defined
I've got a Python CLI app using Click. I have one command in which I defined various options.
This command loads up one of several available environments. (These are reinforcement learning environments, but that doesn't matter for the purpose of this question.) There is an option --env that chooses which environment to load and use. Each environment has different options that I want the user to be able to specify. However, I can't quite define them as options on my command, since I don't know in advance which environment the user will choose.
How can I have my CLI app accept these options?
Possible solutions that I find too ugly:

Define options for all possible environments on the main command.
Pass some kind of string that specifies all the environment options: --env-options "foo=bar baz=7".
Have each environment have its own command with all the options defined on it. This is a problem because (a) people who write environments shouldn't have to know anything about Click and (b) I want to be able to have multiple commands that do things with any chosen environment. So the environment has to be in the realm of "an object that we do different things with" rather than a command that defines what we're doing.


your ugly solutions can be the only solutions. I would use second option --env-options "foo=bar baz=7" because it can be the simplest to code and it can be the most flexible.
